# WPF RichTextBox - disable editing but keep the cursor

Tags: wpf, richtextbox

I have a richtextbox. I need the have the possibility to disable the editing, but I want to keep the cursor: to move between words, to select some words using the keyboard,etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try the `IsReadOnly` property - this should do what you want

Comment: I need to have the cursor in the richtextbox to move it backward, forward. IsReadOnly disables the cursor

Comment: `IsReadOnlyCaretVisible` - you need both

Answer (score 0):

Else try richTextBox1.ReadOnly = true;

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to  improve code formatting and include an explanation of how this works and why it is of solution to the problem described in the question. See [answer].